# Deserializing JSON with multi-level nesting

Tags: c#, json

Yet another mtgjson.com inspired question; none of the other, similar questions are getting me where I need to be.  First, a couple lines of sample JSON (from mtgjson's AllPrices.json):

```
"00028782-6ec2-54fe-8633-2c906d8f1076": {"prices": {"mtgo": {}, "mtgoFoil": {}, "paper": {"2019-12-01": 0.15}, "paperFoil": {}}},
"00040b50-3b84-5cea-b663-70038b87fa08": {"prices": {"mtgo": {"2019-12-02": 0.02}, "mtgoFoil": {"2019-12-02": 0.02}, "paper": {"2019-12-01": 0.15}, "paperFoil": {"2019-12-01": 0.53}}}
```

Each parent object is a GUID and the Price Info; the Price Info is the four types of prices offered, and for each of those four types, the price data is Last Updated Date and Price.

The classes I've created (after lots of other approaches, all of which have failed):

```
public class price_Class
{
    public string Updated { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public class PriceInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("mtgo")] public price_Class mtgo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("mtgoFoil")] public price_Class mtgof { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("paper")] public price_Class RegPrice { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("paperFoil")] public price_Class FoilPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And how I'm using it:

```
dynamic prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJSON);
IDictionary<string, JToken> pricelist = prices;
foreach (var priceline in pricelist)
{
    sUUID = priceline.Key.ToString();
    PriceInfo pi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceInfo>(priceline.Value.ToString());
```

Stepping through in debug mode, I see that prices seems fine; pricelist, also.  The foreach defines priceline as I'd expect, and sUUID is correctly defined - but pi shows up with all four sets of price data as null - not just those that are null, but those that should have data.
priceline.value looks fine, to me:

> {{
>    "mtgo": {},
>    "mtgoFoil": {},
>    "paper": {
>      "2019-12-01": 0.53
>    },
>    "paperFoil": {
>      "2019-12-01": 4.53
>    }
>   }}

When I expand pi in the Locals window, it shows the four classes (FoilPrice, RegPrice, mtgo, mtgof), but the contents are null.

What I need, in case it's not obvious, is to have pi.RegPrice and pi.FoilPrice defined, with a Date and Price, when that data actually exists in the JSON.

I'll admit, nested classes and JSON in general is still outside my comfort zone; I appreciate all help!

Comment: I stead of deserializing again, I would suggest casting it

Comment: In your json updated date is key and price is value in each object. but in your class you have 2 properties for updated date and price. I cannot make it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the odd sub-structure of {Prices:{label:{date:amount}}} just doesn't work well with Newtonsoft's (otherwise excellent) JSON tools.

I tried the various tools (some suggested here) to generate classes; they were getting confused by the dates, creating classes for each date.  I even tried generating classes for just the substring of data (priceline.value, in the example) - nope, still wouldn't work.

I ended going with a brute-force, string manipulation approach; it's ugly, I'm not exactly proud of it - but I now have what I needed.  Here's the relevant snippets, just in case anyone else stumbles on the same things as I did:

```
    private static string RemoveNoise(string input)
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\r\n?|\n", string.Empty); // no more NewLine stuff
        return input.Replace(" ", string.Empty)
            .Replace(@"""",string.Empty); 
    }
    ...
    public class PriceData
    {
        public string UUID { get; set; }
        public string Updated { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string FoilUpd { get; set; }
        public string FoilPrc { get; set; }
    }
    ...
    string sPaperTag = @"PAPER:{";
    string sPprFlTag = @"PAPERFOIL:{";
    ...
    dynamic prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJSON);
    IDictionary pricelist = prices;
    foreach (var priceline in pricelist)
    {
        PriceData pData = new PriceData();
        pData.UUID = priceline.Key.ToString();
        bool bWeHavePrice = false;
        string pi = RemoveNoise(priceline.Value.ToString().ToUpper());
        // parse out paper, paperFoil dates & prices manually (unusual JSON format...)
        iBeg = pi.IndexOf(sPaperTag);
        if (iBeg >= 0)
        {
            sTemp = pi.Substring(iBeg, pi.Length - iBeg);
            iBeg = sTemp.IndexOf(":") + 2;
            iEnd = sTemp.IndexOf("}");
            sTemp = sTemp.Substring(iBeg, iEnd - iBeg); // either YYYY-MM-DD:n.nn, or an empty string
            iBeg = sTemp.IndexOf(":");
            if (iBeg > 0)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParse(sTemp.Substring(0, iBeg), out dtTemp)) { pData.Updated = dtTemp.ToString(); bWeHavePrice = true; }
                if (Decimal.TryParse(sTemp.Substring(++iBeg, sTemp.Length - iBeg), out decTemp)) { pData.Price = decTemp.ToString(); bWeHavePrice = true; }
            }
        }
```

I do that string manipulation dance again for the foil prices; I'm not currently interested in the 'mtgo' or 'mtgoFoil' data.
I'm doing all that TryParse stuff to make sure I have a valid date or amount, but I'm using the results to populate parameters in a SQLCommand, so I have to have strings; seems like extra work, going from string to Date or Decimal, then back to string - but this way I don't get exceptions when executing the SQL Insert command.

My thanks to all who helped, or tried to help.  And if someone figures out how to handle it via JSON.Net, I'd love to see it!

Answer (score 0):

The **price_Class** is not adequate for deserialize your JSON object.

try with this:

```
        public class PriceInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("mtgo")] public Dictionary<string, decimal> mtgo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mtgoFoil")] public Dictionary<string, decimal> mtgof { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("paper")] public Dictionary<string, decimal> RegPrice { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("paperFoil")] public Dictionary<string, decimal> FoilPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That was one of my earlier, unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: don't forget that {"00028782-6ec2-54fe-8633-2c906d8f1076": {"prices": {"mtgo": {}, "mtgoFoil": {}, "paper": {"2019-12-01": 0.15}, "paperFoil": {}}}} is also a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

using this [tool](http://json2csharp.com/) you can find exactly what are your DTO 
the problem are on your json data as i believe date are not send like this in json it come as array of integers and with specific order like day month year .
as well as you need to create your DTO similar to json even in types you can't map it till you set the same type of json in your DTO

```
 public class Prices
    {
        public Mtgo mtgo { get; set; }
        public MtgoFoil mtgoFoil { get; set; }
        public Paper paper { get; set; }
        public PaperFoil paperFoil { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Prices prices { get; set; }
    }
```

don't forget to tag all of them with [JsonProperty("json prop name ")]

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing and formatting utilities for JSON.**

A central concept in lift-json library is Json AST which models the structure of a JSON document as a syntax tree.

```
sealed abstract class JValue
case object JNothing extends JValue // 'zero' for JValue
case object JNull extends JValue
case class JString(s: String) extends JValue
case class JDouble(num: Double) extends JValue
case class JInt(num: BigInt) extends JValue
case class JBool(value: Boolean) extends JValue
case class JField(name: String, value: JValue) extends JValue
case class JObject(obj: List[JField]) extends JValue 
case class JArray(arr: List[JValue]) extends JValue
```

It comes with Lift, but non-Lift users can add lift-json as a dependency in following ways. Note, replace XXX with correct Lift version.

**SBT users**

Add dependency to your project description:

```
val lift_json = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "XXX"
```

**Maven users**

Add dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>lift-json</artifactId>
  <version>XXX</version>
</dependency>
```

**Summary of the features:**

- Fast JSON parser
- LINQ style queries
- Case classes can be used to extract values from parsed JSON
- Diff & merge
- DSL to produce valid JSON
- XPath like expressions and HOFs to manipulate JSON
- Pretty and compact printing
- XML conversions
- Serialization
- Low level pull parser API

Try using this for deeply nested JSONs.